# C# Visual Studio

Tags: c#

I want to create a new C# project in visual studio 2012 but an error appears as follow The name of property stored under the registry key "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolVersions\14.0" has zero length [image: image added]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I suggest that first you [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), and to read the [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) topic so you know how to write a good question in order to receive quick and good answers instead of down votes. After you've done that, you can come back here and edit the question. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall Visual Studio and reinstall it? Also make sure you don't have any 'registry cleaner' software running which can cause these kind of errors.